# jquery autocomplete options not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using jquery autocomplete

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
```

Everything is working Ok., but now I'm trying to add a minChars option which doesn't do anything. My code looks like this:

```
$( "#searchid" ).autocomplete({
    source: "/autocomplete_url.php?more=1", 
    minChars:6,             
    select: function(event, ui) { 
               $("#searchid").val(ui.item.value);
               $("#formid").submit(); 
            }
});
```

Everything is working, except it disregards the options I'm adding. Why/How can I debug the problem?

UPDATE: according to the answer below, I've moved to use minLength instead. I've tried adding in two different ways but it doesn't work :/ This is my "new" code:

```
    $( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ minLength: 6 });        
    $( "#searchid" ).autocomplete({
        source: "/autocomplete_url.php?more=1", 
        minLength:6,        
        select: function(event, ui) { 
               event.preventDefault();
               $("#searchid").val(ui.item.value);
               $("#formid").submit(); 
            }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it ignoring the mincars option or disregarding the options you are adding, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `minChars` but `minLength`
see http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-minLength

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ minLength: 0 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you want to manipulate the form element that the autocomplete itself is attached to, you should include a

```
event.preventDefault();
```

inside your `select: function(event, ui){}` block. Otherwise the default autocomplete behaviour will conflict with your code, as it's also trying to set that value.

Comment: Added to my code (and to the question the exact syntax I used) but didn't work

Comment: Can you clarify what doesn't work? Does the attribute not get the value it should, or does the form not submit, or both? And what is the purpose of the ".selector" class?

Comment: The attribute doesn't get the value it should (submit works). I'm not sure what's the purpose of the ".selector" class, I tried to go with @Marek's answer, although I might have misinterpreted it

Comment: I wondered if that might be the case. Marek's answer was an example, not literal. Unless you have a class named ".selector", that line isn't going to do anything. But if your #searchid also has the selector class, then who knows what you'll get?! Is the AJAX call producing suggestions properly? Then you select an option, and it breaks down: the submit gets called but the form element doesn't have the value it's supposed to. Is that right? Could you update your question with the relevant HTML from your form? It might help to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your source returns JSON with the keys: id, value, and label.  If it doesn't you'll need to use a callback function as your source.   Check out this article on nettus:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/